# main class could not be found or loaded even tough there is a main method

Tags: java, terminal, compiler-errors

I have two classes `ChatClient` and `Listener` and want to comile and run them. In eclipse it works fine, but on terminal I can't get it run. 
Both classes are on the path: `/Desktop/java/task4`.
Maybe I should mention that inside the `ChatClient` class a `Listener` Object gets created.

---

I compile the two classes with the command: `javac *.java` and get 2 classes created. But if I type `java ChatClient` I get the error `main class could not be found or loaded`. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Ubuntu. And yes there is a `main` method inside `ChatClient`

```
public class Listen extends Thread {
Socket s;
Scanner msg;

public Listen(Socket s) {
    ....

}
```

---

```
public class Chatter {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ...
        Listener lt = new Listener(s);
        ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Could you provide some extra information like; classes and commands you use when tried to compile?

Comment: posted my code. @EkremDemirhan I Don't know what you mean by commands. First I type 'javac *.java' and get the classes and then I type 'java ChatClient' and get the error on the title

Comment: There is no package definition in any class ?

Comment: @quinzo I mean if there was no problem when running on Eclipse, it can be caused by the commands you use.

Comment: the path `/Desktop/java/task4` alone is nothing special; what is the class path, which is the directory you are running the `java` command in, what are the packages (if any), what is the complete error message

Comment: `java UE3.ChatClient`, both classes must be in a directory `UE3` and the parent directory of `UE3` must be on the class path (or, when using default, the java command must be called in that parent directory)

Comment: I created a package with eclipse, but I'm not sure if I have to do something extra if I compile& run it on terminal

Comment: Tutorial: [Managing Source and Class Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html) may help

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger exact error message: Error: Could not find or load main class UE3.ChatClient

Comment: you are 2 comments late... my (that) question was for **before** you edited

Comment: @Lemarchand no pac

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities are there to get this error, while running from cmd. Because IDE will do many things related to class path in back ground.

Highest possibility of getting this error is, beginners will not aware of giving the full package structure while running using `java cmd` from correct classpath directory. Please go  to this [link](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/04/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-helloworld-java.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious problem is that you class is in a package (`UE3`) but you have not used the full qualified class name. Try:

```
java UE3.ChatClient
```

There are many other possible problems, such as the classpath not being setup correctly.

(Note the convention for package names is all lowercase. Also rather than extending `Thread` you should typically pass in a `Runnable` as a lambda or method reference.)